# Command to get all possible steps in specflow

Tags: specflow

In Visual studios, when I type in the feature file if the step is not already existing it is highlighted. I want to know is there a command I can write in the command line for a specflow project that can give me a list of all the steps that already exist ?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the Step definition report.
Have a look at the documentation for it [here](http://specflow.org/documentation/Reporting/):

```
specflow.exe stepdefinitionreport <YourPorjectName>.csproj
```

> - Steps with a red background are steps that exist in the automation layer but are not used in any feature files.
> - Steps with a yellow background are steps that exist in a feature file but do not have a corresponding definition.
> - Steps without a special backgrounds are steps that exist both in feature files and the automation layer. Ideally, all your steps are like this.